# Showing Datetime using C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to show timestamp as shown below in my .Net application:

13/12/2007 5:04 PM EST

or

13/12/2007 5:04 PM CST

depending upon the US timezone.

How do i achieve this functionality using C#??

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
```

returns

6/10/2009 7:45:14 PM Central Standard Time

TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName will return the long name and I believe you will have to modify your code a bit to get the abr. for each zone.

Answer (score 4):

You can just call a DateTime's `.ToLongDateString()` method and it will format the result according to the settings on the local system.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method:

```
DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm t K")
```

This will not match your output format exactly, but it will come close.  Since "EST" and "CST" aren't international-friendly, it just displays a divergence from UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here is your solotion

```
    private string ShortTimeZone(string timeZoneFormat)
    {
        string[] TimeZoneElements = timeZoneFormat.Split(' ');
        string shortTimeZone = String.Empty;

        foreach (string element in TimeZoneElements)
        {
            shortTimeZone += element[0];
        }

        return shortTimeZone;
    }
```